# Mapping relationships across Tables (Entity Framework) From ICollections (vb.NET)

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, associations

I'm working on a huge project here and I'll try to simplify the question as much as I can.

It is Basically a DLL which saves the rights of each user to a Database and returns it to the application, this whole thing using Entity Framework.

Here the Classes, I'll not insert all of them, but just two that create a n:m Relashionship:

```
    Public Class Group
Inherits Object
<Key>
Public Property GroupID As Long
<Required>
Public Property GroupName As String
Public Overridable Property Rights As ICollection(Of Rights) = New HashSet(Of Rights)
```

And here the other one:

```
Public Class Rights
<Key>
Public Property ID As Long
<Required>
Public Property Number As Integer
<Required>
 Public Property Name As String
Public Property Description As String
Public Overridable Property Groups As ICollection(Of Groups) = New HashSet(Of Groups)
```

So far so good. This whole data comes from *.csv Files, which I read in as  DataTable, return it to another DLL which takes the DataTable, makes objects from each Class and returns the Objects as an ICollection, this works fine as well.

Here the two functions from this classes, so the two functions that take the data From the DataTable, makes objects out of it and return it as ICollection:

```
Public Function ReturnAllGroups(ByVal dt As DataTable) As ICollection(Of Group) Implements IInfoServiceUtil.ReturnAllGroups

    If dt Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("DataTable can't be nothing", "dt")
    End If

    If Not dt.Columns.Contains("Profile") Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Couldn't find Column Profile")
    End If

    Dim profilNames = From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
    Select row.Field(Of String)("Profile") Distinct

    Dim coll As ICollection(Of Group) = New List(Of Group)

    For Each name In profilNames
        If name <> Nothing Then

            Dim group As Group= New Group()

            groupg.GroupName = name
            coll.Add(group)
        End If
    Next
    Return coll

End Function
```

And here the other onde:

```
 Public Function ReturnAllRights(ByVal dt As DataTable) As ICollection(Of Rights) Implements IInfoServiceUtil.ReturnAllRights
    If dt Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("DataTable can't be nothing!", "dt")
    End If

    If Not dt.Columns.Contains("RightName") Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Couldn't find column RightName!")
    End If

    If Not dt.Columns.Contains("RightNumber") Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Couldn't find column RightNumber!")
    End If

    Dim query = From dr As DataRow In dt.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "RightName", "RightNumber")

    Dim coll As ICollection(Of Rights) = New List(Of Rights)
    For Each row In query
        Dim right As Rights = New Rights()

        If IsNumeric(row.Item("RightNumber")) Then

            With right
                .Name = row.Item("RightName")
                .Number= row.Item("RightNumber")
                coll.Add(right)
            End With

        End If
    Next

    Return coll
End Function
```

This works fine as well. And in this part I'm stucked, coz I'm not sure how I can make the association Table from the Group and Rights Tables.

It would be a Function like this:

```
Public Function CreateAssociation(group As ICollection(Of Groups), right As ICollection(Of Rights), dt As DataTable) As ICollection(Of Group)
    'TODO
    Return coll
End Function
```

Sorry if it's a long question, but any help would be much appreciated. I have more Tables as well, but as soon as I know how to do one, the others will work just fine.
Thanks a lot!